# Sending multiple queryParams in Angular search

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-material

I am having trouble with creating a search for the data I get from an API... the data is displayed in an Angular Material table. I have 8 inputs that can be used as a filter.

How could I append one or more searched terms to the api url that would then show just the filtered results?

Here is the code I have so far and is giving me the error:

> src/app/services/customers.service.ts:23:53 - error TS2339: Property
> 'name' does not exist on type '[]'.
> 23     queryParams = queryParams.append("name", filter.name);

**customers.service.ts**

```
  getAllCustomersList(currentPage: number, filter: []) {

    let queryParams = new HttpParams();
    queryParams = queryParams.append("page", currentPage);
    queryParams = queryParams.append("name", filter.name);

    return this.httpClient.get<Customers>(`${environment.apiUrl}customers`,{params:queryParams});
  }
```

**customers.component.ts**

```
      loadData(filter:[]) {
    
        this.isLoading = true;
    
          this.customerSubscription = this.customersServcice.getAllCustomersList(this.currentPage,filter).subscribe(
              data => {
                this.dataSource.data = data["_embedded"]["customers"];
                setTimeout(() => {
                  this.paginator.pageIndex = this.currentPage;
                  this.paginator.length = data.total_items;
                });
                this.isLoading = false;
              });
      }

      filterChanged(event: any) {
        console.log('Searched value = ' + event.target.value);
        const searchTerm = event.target.value;
    
        this.currentPage = 1;
        this.loadData([])

     }
```

**customers.ts**

```
export interface CustomerItem {
  customer_id: number;
  company_id: number;
  name:  string;
  name2: string;
  address: string;
  post_code: number;
  city: string;
  country_code: string;
  country_name: string;
  phone: string;
  email: string;
  account: string;
  mailing: string;
  sso: string;
  is_customer: string;
  is_vendor: string;
  vat_liable: string;
  vat_number: string
  date_update: string;
  tags: string;
  _links: {
    self: {
      href: string;
    }
  }
}
export interface Customers {
  _links: {
    first: {
      href: string;
    };
    last: {
      href: string;
    };
    next: {
      href: string;
    }
    self: {
      href: string;
    };
  };
  _embedded: {
    customers: CustomerItem[]
  };
  page: number;
  page_count: number;
  page_size: number;
  total_items: number;
}
```

**And here is the html customers.component.html**

```
    <mat-toolbar class="crm-filters-toolbar mat-elevation-z8">
      <mat-toolbar-row>
        <span>Filter</span>
      </mat-toolbar-row>
      <mat-toolbar-row>
        <mat-form-field appearance="outline">
          <mat-label>Name, email...</mat-label>
          <input matInput (keyup)="filterChanged($event)" placeholder="Name, email...">
        </mat-form-field>
        <mat-form-field appearance="outline">
          <mat-label>Customer ID</mat-label>
          <input matInput (keyup)="filterChanged($event)" placeholder="Company ID">
        </mat-form-field>
        <mat-form-field appearance="outline">
          <mat-label>VAT</mat-label>
          <input matInput (keyup)="filterChanged($event)" placeholder="VAT">
        </mat-form-field>
        <mat-form-field appearance="outline">
          <mat-label>Database</mat-label>
          <input matInput (keyup)="filterChanged($event)" placeholder="Database">
        </mat-form-field>
        <mat-form-field appearance="outline">
          <mat-label>Country</mat-label>
          <input matInput (keyup)="filterChanged($event)" placeholder="Country">
        </mat-form-field>
        <mat-form-field appearance="outline">
          <mat-label>Source</mat-label>
          <input matInput (keyup)="filterChanged($event)" placeholder="Source">
        </mat-form-field>
      </mat-toolbar-row>
    </mat-toolbar>
    <div class="table-container">
      <table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource"> 
table rows and columns...
      </table>
    </div>
```

Comment: You define `filter` as an array, and try to access a property by name. It would work better if you define it as an object and then pass an object to the functions. `filter: {}`

Comment: @HarunYilmaz: Was writing the same. I could delete if you can post as an answer

Answer (score 0):

Just pass them as an object

```
let queryParams = {
  page: currentPage
  name: filter[0]
};
// ...
this.httpClient.get<Customers>(`${environment.apiUrl}customers`, {params: queryParams });
```

also you are passing `filter: []` as an array. That won't let you do `filter.name`. Only indexing will work. Like `filter[0]`

---

**Update:**
Use `string[]` instead of `[]` in the signature like this

```
getAllCustomersList(currentPage: number, filter: string[])
```

Comment: this is the error that I'm getting now
TS2493: Tuple type '[]' of length '0' has no element at index '0'.

26       name: filter[0]

Answer (score 0):

Here you are defining the type of the filter as [] in getAllCustomerList

```
getAllCustomersList(currentPage: number, filter: any) { // or use type if you have defined any.
```

You should use the type for filters or simply use any if there is not type for that.

I assume the filter is an Object so you can define as "any" or if its an array you would need to mention that as

```
 getAllCustomersList(currentPage: number, filter: any[]) { // or Array<any>
```

Comment: How do I use the type for filters?

Comment: In Function definition you are using [] as type but that but that can not be used as type instead use above example, and to use that array in api call you need to create an object of that array like {filter : filter} , in this the value part is the array.